# Does the yield of Celastrus Trees Increase with Magic Secateurs and Attas Seeds?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

I learned today that the yield of [Celastrus trees](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Celastrus_tree) can be increased when you compost the patch.  But do other yield boosting means impact it? I've tried searching around, but it seems most websites that talk about it either experience a 500 web response or 404 amusingly.  The wiki only states that compost boosts yields and mentions nothing else.

Do these boost the yield:

- Magic Sceaterus (10%)
- Attas seed planted (5%)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a look on the Wiki for the [Celastrus Bark](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Celastrus_bark):

> One Celastrus tree produces a minimum of 3 bark, where each harvest has a chance of using up one of the "lives" of the Celastrus patch, much like harvesting herb patches. Similar to other variable-yield patches, yield of Celastrus bark can be increased by using Magic secateurs[1](https://twitter.com/JagexAsh/status/1250487359730302978), Supercompost, Ultracompost and having higher farming levels. It is currently unconfirmed if the attas plant affects the amount of lives a celastrus tree has.

It appears compost and Magic Secateurs do impact - Attas isn't confirmed.

edit: it is now [confirmed!](https://twitter.com/JagexAsh/status/1250487359730302978)

Comment: @TimmyJim it may be worth tweeting mod ash if he's able to confirm the Attas impact - he's generally good at replying

Comment: The king has spoken: https://twitter.com/JagexAsh/status/1250487359730302978 - Attas plants do impact it!